# Migrating hardcoded query from MYSQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, migration, hardcoded

Hi I have one "mysql" query that looks like this:

```
... WHERE (maintenanceLockTimestamp + "+ delay+" SECOND) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) "
```

The thing is that, we need to move from MYSQL to PostgreSQL, but when executing the same query, I get:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SECONDS"
```

I checked here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/

and it looks like the SECOND function is not present in PostgreSQL, do you know any alternative?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can use:

```
where maintenanceLockTimestamp + :delay * interval '1 second' < current_timestamp
```

Note the use of a *parameter* to avoid munging the query string with literal values.

In both databases, this is better written with the date/time arithmetic on the `current_timestamp`:

```
where maintenanceLockTimestamp < current_timestamp - ? second  -- MySQL
where maintenanceLockTimestamp < current_timestamp - :delay * interval '1 second'  -- Postgres
```

This allows the optimizer to use an index on `maintenanceLockTimestamp` for performance.

Comment: what an amazing answer.... incredible. I fixed that issue, now I have another one related to the naming strategy, since my table is named in the entity with @Table(name=NodeInfo) but in postgres I have node_info. But the 'seconds'problem is working. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I'm getting this:
Thanks for your answer, I still get this:
PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying * interval
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @Manuelarte . . . You need to pass the parameter in as a number or convert to a number in Postgres -- say `:delay::int * interval '1 second'`.